# How do I get the know the default capacity provider strategy for ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs

How do I find out the default capacity provider strategy for ECS? If I create a capacity provider strategy from the web console does the first one become the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the current default (if any exists) by clicking on the cluster, and clicking the blue "update cluster" button in the upper right.